# Configuring jOOQ to use the Kotlin IO dispatcher

Tags: kotlin, jooq

The default executor in jOOQ [uses the ForkJoinPool common pool by default](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/main/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/DefaultExecutor.java#L50-L53), or plain unmanaged threads when only one CPU is available:

Since I use a standard blocking JDBC driver (as opposed to an async driver like r2dbc), most of the time jOOQ threads spend will be waiting for I/O, it is advisable to allocate more threads than provided by the `ForkJoinPool` common pool, the default sizes of which seem to be configured more for CPU-intensive work.

I'm using Kotlin coroutines, what would the best way be to integrate jOOQ's executor with my Kotlin `Dispatchers.IO` thread pool, which has a [better default configuration for threads](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html#:%7E:text=The%20CoroutineDispatcher%20that%20is%20designed%20for%20offloading%20blocking%20IO%20tasks%20to%20a%20shared%20pool%20of%20threads.) doing blocking IO?

Answer (score 1):

With Kotlin, the IO dispatcher can be obtained as an executor using the `asExecutor()` extension function. Therefore, configuring jOOQ to use it is simple:

```kotlin
DSL
  .using(
    DefaultConfiguration()
      .set(ExecutorProvider { Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor() })
  )
```